# Nested set model query select nodes inside a parent

Tags: mysql, treeview, nested, hierarchy, hierarchical-data

I have a nested set model as follows.

```
HOME
  MUSIC
   GUITAR
   KEY BOARD
   RADIO

  FURNITURE
   BDD
   TABLE

  BOOKS
   BIBLE
   Godfather
```

My question is with query how to display the child elements in a parent ?
For eg.

List `MUSIC, FURNITURE, BOOKS` for parent as `HOME`
List `GUITAR,KEY BOARD, RADIO` for parent as `MUSIC`

I have tried the following query

```
select * from elements where lft between 1 and 22 order by lft asc
```

for selecting the first parents child, but it returning the entire list.

Can any one please help me ?

Thanks in advance

the table structure looks like

```
-------+-------------------+------------+----------
id     |     cat_name      |   lft      |   rgt
-------|-------------------+------------+----------
1      |       HOME        |   1        |   22
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you what you want:

```
SELECT
    c.cat_name
FROM
    tree_struc t
JOIN
    tree_struc c
    ON c.lft BETWEEN t.lft + 1 AND t.rgt - 1
LEFT JOIN
    tree_struc a
    ON a.lft BETWEEN t.lft + 1 AND t.rgt - 1
    AND c.lft BETWEEN a.lft + 1 AND a.rgt - 1
WHERE t.cat_name = 'Music' AND a.id IS NULL;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dead5/1)

Comment: thanks for your reply. is this query works for any deep structure ?

Comment: Yes it does, the fiddle example is with home, but music or books will also give the right results. If you need more explanation feel free to ask

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion the best way is to do the following, using :p_parent_id as a substitution variable, which holds the ID of the category, which children you want to retrieve:

```
select * from elements where parent_id = :p_parent_id
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. But I am confused with parent_id. Updated my table structure in question. Can u please check ?

Comment: You're talking about adjacency list here and OP has a nested set.